# Detect transaction in session

Tags: sql, database, odbc

Is there an ODBC API call to detect that a session has a transaction going on? In other words, can I detect that an executed statement(s) is part of a transaction?

I realize that, for most DBMSes, setting `AUTOCOMMIT` to `off` means that any statement after that becomes part of a transaction. However, a single `SELECT` statement should not have to require explicit `COMMIT`, and I'm trying to find a way to query the driver about what's actually going on, rather than trying to figure out myself what's in a query string.

Answer (score 0):

I think the ODBC API itself does not provide a direct function to check if a session is currently within a transaction. The state of transactions (whether ongoing, committed, or rolled back) is typically managed by the DBMS, and the ODBC driver may or may not show it.

But I think you can use `SQLGetConnectAttr` function with `SQL_ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT` attribute to check the auto-commit mode status. If auto-commit is off,  statements are part of a transaction until a commit or rollback is issued.

To know the exact transaction state, you need to rely on DBMS-specific SQL queries/functions